# Configure wcf service programmatically

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security, wcf-binding, wcf-data-services

I have a remote wcf service, I connect it by WSHttpBinding. If I use the empty service constructor which mean it will take all the configurations from the app.config , everything is ok, (I mean MyService s = new MyService()).
Now I want to configure the wcf programmatically . it's simple till I arrive to the authentication issue , it was so hard to do that . Here is the app.config which I use , you can see there my security configurations .

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="SecuredEndPoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="true" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>               
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://MyWcfService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecuredEndPoint"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IMyService" name="SecuredEndPoint">
            <identity>
                <certificate encodedValue="*******************************************************************" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>            
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have done this, you might have to modify your code for security mode you have in config

```
public virtual ChannelFactory<T> Proxy<T>(string address) {
      //Validate Address
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address)) throw new ArgumentNullException("Address can not be null or empty.");
      //Address
      EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(address);

      //Binding
      WSHttpBinding wsHttpBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None, false);
      wsHttpBinding.OpenTimeout = wsHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
      wsHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = wsHttpBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
      wsHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = wsHttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
      wsHttpBinding.BypassProxyOnLocal = wsHttpBinding.AllowCookies = wsHttpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
      wsHttpBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
      wsHttpBinding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
      wsHttpBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
      wsHttpBinding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
      wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas(); //ReaderQuotas, setting to Max
      wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
      wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
      wsHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;

      //Create the Proxy
      ChannelFactory<T> proxy = new ChannelFactory<T>(wsHttpBinding, endpointAddress);

      //Sets the MaxItemsInObjectGraph, so that client can receive large objects
      foreach (var operation in proxy.Endpoint.Contract.Operations) {
          DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior operationBehavior = operation.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
          //If DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior is not present in the Behavior, then add
          if (operationBehavior == null) {
              operationBehavior = new DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(operation);
              operation.Behaviors.Add(operationBehavior);
          }
          //IMPORTANT: As 'operationBehavior' is a reference, changing anything here will automatically update the value in list, so no need to add this behavior to behaviorlist
          operationBehavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647;
      }
      return proxy;
 }
```

On this `proxy` object you will need to do `.CreateChannel()` to use it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But where I can see the certificate encodedValue issue in the identity code , this was really my big problem .

Comment: Try this `EndpointIdentity identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Your Certificate"));` and put give this identity to `EndpointAddress` constructor. You will have to modify Security Mode.

Comment: I got : Client cannot determine the Service Principal Name based on the identity in the target address http://MyService.svc/securedendpoint' for the purpose of SspiNegotiation/Kerberos. The target address identity must be a UPN identity (like acmedomain\alice) or SPN identity (like host/bobs-machine). My code to set the idenetiy is : var encodedValue =
                "****Y";
            EndpointIdentity identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodedValue)));

Comment: did you know, that there's eg `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int seconds)` - instead of doing sth like `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, int seconds)` :)

Comment: Yes. This had written this code almost 2 yrs back. Are you crawling my post ;) I guess I need to start refactoring my code :)

Comment: :) just go interested in your person and realized you did some pretty good answers ...