# Tutorial on consuming WCF 4.0 with Asp.net in Vs2010

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I want a good tutorial with WCF on VS2010. This service will be consumed in an ASP.Net Mvc 2/3.
The development will be done in VS2010.

[This](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2010/12/15/create-and-consume-wcf-service-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx) is a good start, but still not exactly what I need.

Can anyone recommend a good tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you have provided is very good, it has shown all the steps of creating and consuming WCF service. The only difference in your case is, the client. You want consume WCF service in ASP.Net MVC, and in the tutorial the client is console app.

Following are some of the links which might help you

1. Scott Guthrie's [Nerd Dinner](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx) walkthrough to get a really good understanding of MVC basics.
2. How to [Configure wcf service programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820105/configure-wcf-service-programatically)
3. Blogs on how to write a Layered ASP.NET MVC Applicaiton with a WCF Service

   - [Part I](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/a-layered-aspnet-mvc-application-part-i/) (General Concepts)
   - [Part II](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/a-layered-aspnet-mvc-application-part-ii/) (Building a Repository)
   - [Part III](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/a-layered-aspnet-mvc-application-part-iii/) (Building The Service)
   - [Part IV](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/a-layered-aspnet-mvc-application-part-iv/) (Using The Service)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeah, but I need the part where he adds a service reference and configures it in vs 2010

Comment: To create WCF service reference you can use [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) to create the reference.

Comment: Yeah, but this takes a lot of time, and i have to do that for every change i make in the service. Is there no other way?

Comment: You only update service reference when you modify contracts (either DataContract or ServiceContract or both), if you change logic inside service you don't have to update the service reference. To change it you can do it from Visual Studio, from Solution explorer select **Service Reference** and from that you can add/update the reference. Otherwise you can have a script or batch file which can update the service reference for you (which I do).