# WCF Security - Https and Anonymous Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, https

We have a service that is currently using basicHttpBinding. We have the flexibility to convert it to netTCPBinding. While deploying it in IIS 7, we are using authentication as Anonymous. The service is accessed by a website hosted in IIS in same network.

Our client raised a concern about anonymous authentication and he doesn’t want unwanted users (in the office network) to use it. The point is people can create their own sample website and consume the service.

Suppose I am using **Transport Credential Type** as "**Certificate**", will it meet my requirement? I.e., only users having the client certifcate can access the service? Can you direct me to any article that explains how to implment it?

```
<endpoint address=""
binding="basicHttpBinding"
```

I have referred the following
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx

Note:The consuming website in IIS uses Windows Authentication: Enabled, ASP.NET impersonation: Enabled

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to convert to netTCP and use the certificate authentication . Share the certificate only with the website which access the web service. Below link will help you to achieve the certificate security in WCF

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36683/9-simple-steps-to-enable-X-509-certificates-on-WCF

Comment: So you are saying that the https with certifcate will meet the requirement, isn' it?

Comment: no .I suggested netTCP with certificate as your consumer is a .net website .If you use https, I think anybody can hit that url and download the certificate.

Comment: Suppose I am using Transport Credential Type as "Certificate", will it meet my requirement? I.e., only users having the client certifcate can access the service?

Comment: Yes, client certificates can be used with both HTTPS and TCP. There is extra configuration in IIS for requiring client certificates.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution can be you use `Http Headers`, and put some auth key in the headers when client makes the request. On the server check the request headers for the auth key. If key is not found, fault the service. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820105/configure-wcf-service-programatically/8820216#8820216) post which explains how to add headers while creating proxy of the service.

**Suggestion**

You can remove the meta data endpoint (mex), set [httpGetEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicemetadatabehavior.httpgetenabled.aspx) to `false`, this way nobody will able to create proxy of the service.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Try to change security mode to transport in the config. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729700.aspx). By making `https` you are securing the transport layer. I guess this should work for you.

Comment: Also check this [WCF Bindings Needed For HTTPS](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/20/wcf-bindings-needed-for-https.aspx)

Comment: Even if we make the transport layer secure, unwnated people in the same netwrok can consume it, right?

Comment: Yes, but if they have Service Proxy. You can try `Message Security` with `certificate`. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731884.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx. In this case unwanted people can hit the service, but their call will fail.

Comment: Yes, user with certificate will able to make service call with success in response.

Comment: You can check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd728058 (Sample code), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751516.aspx, http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2006/09/24/931.aspx, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18601/An-easy-way-to-use-certificates-for-WCF-security or you can check on google, lots of sample are available.

Comment: any of the security with certificate. If you choose `transport`, you will need to host service on `https`. The difference in message and transport is, in message you secure data and not the connnection and in transport, you secure the connection and not the data.