# How to create WCF Service Library in Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to learn how to create a WCF Service and host in on IIS. However, all the tutorials I can find on the net are for creating WCF Service Library, whereas Visual Studio Exrpesss only has WCF Service Application.

Does anybody know how to get the WCF Service Library in VS Express 2010? I don't have it in my VS application

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a template which Visual Studio provides.

To create WCF library you can create any normal Class Library, add two references

- [System.Runtime.Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd1dc9w5.aspx)
- [System.ServiceModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.aspx)

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks! What about the APP.Config file? Its all quiet confusing

Comment: WCF is very flexible. Always remember it works ABC (Address, Bindign & Contract). Your Contract goes in Library, where as address and binding goes in config (if you are using one, it's not mandatory though, you can have WCF service without config file). And if you are hosting in IIS, you will need `web.config`. You can check [Configuration Editor Tool (SvcConfigEditor.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx)

Comment: Class libraries do NOT have an app.config (or web.config) file - they use the config file of the consuming application.

Comment: Config file is involved when you are hosting the WCF service or consuming it, again this is optional, you can host or consume WCF service through coding. Check [Configure wcf service programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820105/configure-wcf-service-programatically) post

Comment: Question was about WCF Service Library template. Is it possible to download it to Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express or Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express? I don't see any option like that...