# Adding custom header to generated SOAP proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, wsdl, soapheader, generated

I have generated a proxy class from a wsdl file (C# VS 2008)
The webservice expects an element within the soap header. 
When I try to add this element using `proxy.RequestSoapContext.Envelope.Header` I receive a null error. The envelope is null.
How do I am a custom element to the header ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
EndpointAddressBuilder endpointAddressBuilder = 
          new EndpointAddressBuilder(proxy.Endpoint.Address);
foreach (var item in headers) //headers is a Dictionary<string, string>
     endpointAddressBuilder.Headers.Add(
          AddressHeader.CreateAddressHeader(item.Key, "nameSpace", item.Value));
proxy.Endpoint.Address = endpointAddressBuilder.ToEndpointAddress();
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thankyou Amar. That worked! It took me a while as my generated proxy was from wsdl.exe rather than svcutil.exe.

Comment: On the off chance I am now getting the error No SOAPAction Header defined. Any thoughts ?  I'm new to web services and find it a mine field of objects etc.

Comment: Answered this myself. Switched from WcfBinding to Basic.

Comment: Great to hear that. You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820105/configure-wcf-service-programatically) post also, might help you.

Comment: Hi Amar. I hope its not inappropriate to ask a question like this. Its just you know the context and it might be easier to answer. I am using client.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign This doesnt fully work as the URI of the signature points to _0 but the message body does not have an ID. I have been pulling my hair out looking for where to specify an ID. Any suggestions would be most welcome. (As an aside I find the MS way of implementing web services the most messy and awkward) Kind regards  Tom

Comment: Sorry but never done this. Will check this over the weekend and will try to answer your question.

Comment: Thankyou Amar. You have been a great help.